# jQuery click event stop working in plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I've been trying to add event listeners as a part of a plugin. The idea is really simple, the goal is to do a slider plugin that handles 2 dimensions (horizontally and vertically)

So I have something like this

```
<div class="tab-container bg-dark-blue" start-tab="Home">

    <div class="tab-page" x-index="1" y-index="1" id="Home">
        <h1>x=1, y=1</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-page" x-index="1" y-index="2">
        <h1>x=1, y=2</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-page" x-index="2" y-index="1">
        <h1>x=2, y=1</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-page" x-index="2" y-index="2">
        <h1>x=2, y=2</h1>
    </div>

</div>
```

Where tab-page divs are absolutely positioned with 100% width and height, and tab-container is relatively positioned with 100% width and height of the browser.

```
var __MyMethods = {
width : 0
height : 0,
container : null,
// other stuff
setup : function(tab_container) {
// setup __MyPlugin.container = tab_container
// setup width, height of the container
},
            /*
         * Movement functions
         *
         */
        move : function(direction)
        {

            if( direction == 'left' )
            {
                __MyMethods.x--;
                __MyMethods.translate( 'left', __MyMethods.width );
                //
            }

            if( direction == 'right' )
            {
                __MyMethods.x++;
                __MyMethods.translate( 'left', (-1)*__MyMethods.width );

                //
            }

            if( direction == 'up' )
            {
                __MyMethods.y--;
                __MyMethods.translate( 'top', __MyMethods.height );
            }

            if( direction == 'down' )
            {
                //
                __MyMethods.y++;
                __MyMethods.translate( 'top', (-1)*__MyMethods.height );
                //
            }


        },


        translate : function(property, offset)
        {


            // For each .tab-page in we animate the CSS property
            $(__MyMethods.container).children(".tab-page").each( function() {
                var animation = {};

                var x = parseInt( $(this).css(property).replace('px','') ) + offset;


                animation[property] = x.toString() + 'px';

                $(this).animate(
                    animation,
                    {
                        'duration' : 0,
                        'queue' : false,
                    }
                );

            });


        },


    };
$.fn.MyPlugin = function()
{
    __MyMethods.setup(this);


    $(".btn").click( function(event)
    {
        __MyMethods.move( $(this).attr("move") );
        console.log(this);
    });


    return this;
};
```

So I put

```
<button class="btn" move="up"></button>
<button class="btn" move="down"></button> 
<button class="btn" move="left"></button>
<button class="btn" move="right"></button>
```

Somewhere in the HTML and it works fine for up, left, right... but if you click the move="down" button it works only the first time.

I don't know why is that hapening, the event never fires again if you click that button, I tried doing console.log(this) inside the click event function, but it doesn't show anything after the down button is clicked...

Any idea of what can be happening?

Thank you very much for any help you can give me

**Edit**: Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/on1bLnrv/)

Regards

Comment: Better if you could create a [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Hello! Thanks for response I created this demo http://jsfiddle.net/on1bLnrv/

Comment: Don't use custom attributes like `x-index`, `y-index` - use `data-*` attribute instead like `data-x-index`, `data-y-index`

Comment: Also, your *slider*, on many clicks will go totally off-view!

Comment: Instead of animating **every** single item on your page, **animate only one**: the parent that contains your *pages* elements

Comment: Also, if you're creating a plugin, me, as a user of that plugin I'd find it extremely difficult to handle and reorganize the *pages* X,Y indexes. Think how much simpler would be to instantiate the plugin using: `grid: [3,4] /* default to "square"*/` > and let the plugin automatically create a 3x4 or square NxN (depending on the number of DIV pages children...)

Comment: Also, from a designer/programmer perspective, (if you stick to indexes) I'd logically expect index 0 to be the 0th *initial* position (1 as the second etc.)

Comment: Thanks for advices! I will use them, I just wanted something to start. @RokoC.Buljan which property would be useful to animate? I've been researching to find out the best method to do this

Comment: @David well, the best suggestion is to use CSS3 `transition` and animate the parent element's `transform: translate(Xhere, Yhere)` - and inside the same animateTo() function create a fallback to `left / top` if the browser does not supports CSS3 (rare today but there's still lot of such).

Comment: @David my other best suggestion is: since logically one cannot have a single page with loads of such sliders (since that silder is meant to cover the whole window) - don't bother with huge *Plugin*s that calculate unneeded widths, heights etc.... Instead prepare a better responsive CSS (using %) and just a plain simple animate logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you jsfiddle the down button seems to stay behind the tab-page s. Giving z-index to menu and tab-page elements solves the problem.

In your css file:
Add

```
z-index: 10;
```

to .menu

Add

```
z-index: 1;
```

to .tab-page

[css](/questions/tagged/css)

Comment: :D hahaha who would say! Nice found

Comment: @rgucluer Incredible, just thanks. As Roko has said: nice found!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I will do changes to implement your advices too, maybe adding a class or something to animate, and generate some divs with the javascript. Thank you very much!